# Is there a difference between "government-bonds" and "treasury" tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

Description for [government-bonds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government-bonds):

> for questions that relate to government bonds. It is recommend you use a country tag or state what country you are referring to. A government bond is a bond issued by a national government, generally promising to pay a certain amount on a certain date, as well as periodic interest payments.

[treasury](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasury) has no tag description. Practically all the questions there are about US government bonds. Only one question is specifically about the US Department of the Treasury.

Is there a difference between the "government-bonds" and "treasury" tags? Should they be merged? If not, do you think "treasury" should refer specifically to the US Department of the Treasury?

Answer (score 1):

My only counter-argument is that [government-bonds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government-bonds) could be about *any* government's bonds, while [treasury](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasury) is probably specific to the US. I could go for either retagging them as [government-bonds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government-bonds) and adding a [united-states](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tag, or renaming [treasury](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasury) to [treasury-bonds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasury-bonds), but that's a subset of [government-bonds](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/government-bonds) in my opinion.